# How to cancel operation correctly in odata

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I want to cancel loading entities when canceled from client side. I have controller, it looks like this:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> products = Context.GetEntities<Product>();

        return Ok();
    }
    List<Product> GetInsTance(IQueryable<Product> products,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var list = new List<Product>();
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I'm throwing exception when it's canceled. So, I want to do cancelation by different way. What if I set `IQuerable` to `OK` method? Will it work? Is there any another way to do this?